# C++ using move semantics to pass argument to another function

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference, move-semantics

I have function which takes 2 arguments, but one of these (map container) is passed to another function:

```
void myFunc(const std::map<std::string, int> &myMap, int num) {
    int x = internalFunc(myMap);
    // do some stuff...
}

int internalFunc(const std::map<std::string, int> &myMap) {
    // return some map statistics
}
```

somewhere in main.cpp :

```
std::map<std::string, int> map1{ {"Hello", 10}, {"Hello2", 20}, {"Hello3", 30} };
myFunc(map1, 20);
```

My question is:

Is move semantics a good way for optimising this piece of code (passing one argument to another function using move) like this:

```
int internalFunc(std::map<std::string, int> &&myMap) {
    // now gets rvalue reference
    // return some map statistics
}

void myFunc(std::map<std::string, int> myMap, int num) {
    int x = internalFunc(std::move(myMap));
    // do some stuff...
}
```

I prefer not to use universal reference (using template) and std::forward in this case because this function is always called with this type of map and I prefer to keep the code as simple as possible.

internalFunc is always called by this one specific function myFunc.

Is move semantics good way for optimising this kind of functions? I understand that optimising using move semantics depends on moved object type, but let's stick to the example above with standard map container.

Thank you

Comment: If `myFunc` or `internalFunc` copies the map (or some strings out of it), and `map1` is not used after passing it to `myFunc`, then moving could be useful. Otherwise, you don't need to change anything.

Comment: "*Is move semantics a good way for optimising this piece of code (passing one argument to another function using move) like this:*" Wait: you've changed the very nature of the code here. In your first example, it took a `const&`. In the second, `myFunc` takes the parameter by value, which requires copy/move-ing from the caller's data. That's a completely different function now.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, map1 is not used after this function call. Nicol, yes that is true, in my project this function works with const references right now, it doesn;t change the map structure at all. However I was wondering if this could be potencially slow, because myFunc doesn't use map, just passes it to next function.

PS: In the project real map object contains hundreds of records, above example is simplified.

Comment: @Rafal Ok, but do you copy anything from the map in any of these functions? (copying `int`s doesn't count)

Comment: No, I just do some statistics calculation, don't pass any of map elements further or use it, just read-only usage.

Comment: @Rafal Then you don't need to move anything. Moving can be used instead of copying in some cases, but since you don't copy anything to begin with, using const references is the best solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move semantics are useful if you need to modify the `map` or if the function needs to take ownership of the `map` for some reason (maybe the latter is more understandable if the functions were class members, i.e. setters or constructors for instance).

You should use `const std::map<std::string, int>&` for 3 main reasons:

1. You only want read access.
2. Readability: the user will understand quickly that the `map` won't be modified.
3. You won't get better results using `move` semantics.

**Note on move semantics**

If you use move semantics, the arguments of your functions don't necessarily need the double `&&`. Generally, it is better to omit them (except for perfect forwarding and non-copyable objects like stream objects). The `&&` requires that the passed arguments be `rvalues`. However, omitting the `&&` does **not** mean you cannot pass the arguments as `rvalues`. Let's see this with an example:

```
int internalFunc(std::map<std::string, int> myMap)
{
    /* ... */
    return 1; // or whatever
}

void myFunc(std::map<std::string, int> myMap, int num)
{
    int x = internalFunc(std::move(myMap));
    // do some stuff...
}
```

The arguments `myMap` in the above code **don't get copied** if you pass them as `rvalues`:

```
int main()
{
    myFunc({ {"Hello", 10}, {"Hello2", 20}, {"Hello3", 30} }, 20);
    return 0;
}
```

Moreover, you can now use the same code by passing `lvalues`, like you do in the `main` function of your question (`myFunc(map1, 20);`). The argument `myMap` in `myFunc` is then a copy of course. Also, your version with move semantics would not compile in this case.

If you really want to make sure the maps don't get copied, you can use the `&&`, but this is rather rare, and, in my opinion, should be used only for objects which cannot be copied (i.e. stream objects).

Comment: Thanx @mfnx , for a precise answer. I'd like to point out:
>> _The arguments myMap in the above code don't get copied if you pass them as rvalues: ..._
Caution: This is true thanks to the move semantics introduced in C++11. However in earlier standards of c++ compilers (C++03 and below) this there would be a copy too.
I hope I am not mistaken..

Comment: @SoldOut The question is about move semantics. No need to mention earlier standards.

Comment: I understand - your answer is great, and it helped me. I just supplied that info to help others (younger) to realize that limitation, for the case they deal with a legacy code & compilers. I hope it will be more of help, rather than confusion :)